# A comic book about searching for girl who teleports in time inside the sphere

Tags: story-identification, comics

Please help me identify a comic book about searching for girl who teleports through time in a bubble (she is naked as I remember). The girl is lost in time and all the adventures that happen are about jumping through time in an attempt to rescue her.  This comic book is from 80's or early 90's and it's probably french comic book.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This might be Les Naufragés du temps (translates to something like "Shipwrecked in time")  by Paul Gillon and Jean-Claude Forest. There is actually no timetravel but hibernation in spaceships (to save the heroes, a perfect couple, from armaggedon on earth), but the story is all about saving the girl (well that and saving the world), she is frozen in a bubble (multiple times if I remember correctly) an all adventures are about rescuing her. The series started in 1968 but the last part was published in 1989, so it matches your timeframe.

Girl-in-bubble-image stolen from the interweb (I claim fair use):

[image]

Comment: yes, this is it !

Comment: mayby you could help me with this : http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/82497/please-help-identify-an-old-scifi-comic-book-1970-1990-probably-french   (this is the last one)